# Package restore failed for xamarinforms project in visual studio 2017

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

error message is : **Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'XFDemo.Android'".**

steps to generate this error :
 1. create new xamarinforms project.
 2. right click on solution => select "Manage NuGet Packages for solution".
 3. from "NuGet Solution" windows I choose update tab.
 4. select all items then click on update.
 5. aftr I tried to update I got the error message "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'XFDemo.Android'"

how I can solve this issue ?

I tried to clear NuGet Packages cache but the clear is faild.

Comment: Try setting your Android target framework to latest & greatest.

Comment: install Oreo 8.1 SDK/Tools via Android SDK Manager and in properties of your app, select targetframework to last Oreo version.

Comment: Thank you very much @magicandre1981 its work with me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issue is as mentioned above 
I just install Oreo 8.1 SDK/Tools via Android SDK Manager and in properties of your app, select target framework to last Oreo version. –

and its work :)